# Как вывести подсказку(Hovertipe) у кнопки в виде текста?

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь вывести в своей программе текст у кнопки, но выдаёт ошибку, не могу как можно исправить, вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#Импортирование класса Hovertip из исходного кода.
from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip

#Создание окна.
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1200x900')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)                        
root.title('Курсовая')

#Создание холста.
c = Canvas(root,height=900, width=1200, bg='white')
c.place(x=0,y=0)

#Загрузка фото всего ПК.
image1 = Image.open('fon.jpg')#открываем фото
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
image = c.create_image(0, 0,image = photo1,anchor='nw')

#Загрузка цифр.
image2 = Image.open('1.jpg')
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
image3 = Image.open('2.jpg')
photo3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
image4 = Image.open('3.jpg')
photo4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)
image5 = Image.open('4.jpg')
photo5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image5)
image6 = Image.open('5.jpg')
photo6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image6)
image7 = Image.open('6.jpg')
photo7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image7)
image8 = Image.open('7.jpg')
photo8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image8)
image9 = Image.open('8.jpg')
photo9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image9)
image10 = Image.open('9.jpg')
photo10 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image10)
image11 = Image.open('10.jpg')
photo11 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image11)

#Создание кнопок для цифр.
number1 = Button(c,image = photo2, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=100, y=10)#блок питания
number2 = Button(c,image = photo3, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=600, y=500)#ОЗУ
number3 = Button(c,image = photo4, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=750, y=20)#DVD
number4 = Button(c,image = photo5, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=780, y=270)#хард
number5 = Button(c,image = photo6, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=170, y=800)#видеокарта
number6 = Button(c,image = photo7, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=130, y=390)#системный куллер(выдув)
number7 = Button(c,image = photo8, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=1070, y=720)#системный куллер(вдув)
number8 = Button(c,image = photo9, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=445, y=420)#проц/куллер
number9 = Button(c,image = photo11, width = 20, height = 20, border = '0').place(x=210, y=500)#порт Ethernet !!! (20x20 пикс) !!!
number10 = Button(c,image = photo10, width = 30, height = 30, border = '0').place(x=400, y=600)#радиатор матплаты


#Вывод мини-подсказки.
Hovertip(number1,text="Блок питания \nнажмите для большей информации.",hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number2,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number3,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number4,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number5,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number6,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number7,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number8,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number9,'w',hover_delay=100)
Hovertip(number10,'w',hover_delay=100)



c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Вот сама ошибка]

Comment: Здесь пробел не нужен между запятой и text ? number1,text

Comment: Разместите скрин ошибки.

Comment: Разместил ошибку.